# NODE_ENV=development doesn't work on windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows, npm-install

i am having the problem while i am trying to start a fragment in a dev-mode (npm run build).
it throw an Error

```
module.js:471
  throw err;
  Error: Cannot find module '../../dist/assets/1.05805d01bc06f054a19d4.js'.
```

I've tried the solution with cross-env but i didn't worked.

Makefile contains

```
dev:    
    NODE_ENV=production CDN_PATH=/ $(npm_bin)/webpack
    NODE_ENV=development node server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
       "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross-env` module for maximum portability also in the Makefile. Just make sure you have `./node_modules/.bin` in your PATH or you use a full:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server ...
```

Of course it will work only after `npm install`

Also you can find some other ways o specifically change the environment on Windows in Makefiles but since you're already using `cross-env` then you may as well use it.

Comment: it show me now another error: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."